# In which Wings Of Liberty missions can you play as the Zerg?

Tags: starcraft-2

Are there any missions in the Starcraft 2: Wings of Liberty campaign where you can play as the Zerg?

If so, which missions?

Comment: Do you mean Protoss?

Comment: I know there are some protoss missions, but I thought there was a Zerg mission too?

Comment: I can't remember there being one off the top of my head, although I could be wrong. I do remember Zeratul's Protoss missions however

Comment: Now I remember: There was one mission where you could overtake a zerg building and start build zerg units that way

Comment: Out of curiosity, which mission was that? I remember building up my zerg tech level just to get to the mind control tower thing, but even then you couldn't capture drones! such as waste :P

Comment: I don't remember which it was and how I did it, I played the campaign some years ago and I am still a beginner ;)

Comment: Nope, never happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are **no playable zerg missions** in the WoL campaign.

You don't play zerg even on the **secret mission**:

- Rebellion 5: Piercing the Shroud

There are few **protoss missions** however:

- Prophecy 1: Whispers of Doom
- Prophecy 2: A Sinister Turn
- Prophecy 3: Echoes of the Future
- Prophecy 4: In Utter Darkness

[Here](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Campaign) is the list of all missions,you can check each one and see for yourself.