# Where can a new player start with Zerg in Starcraft II?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

I'm new to Starcraft and have been playing the campaigns. Right now, I'm in the mood for wanton destruction and the Zerg sound like fun. So with that in mind:

**How do I play as the Zerg in Starcraft II?**

I'm not asking for advice on how to play them *well*, but how to play them *at all*. I played the Zerg a bit in the tutorial and I like the taste. I haven't found any campaigns that allow me to play as them. I found [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126090/in-which-wings-of-liberty-missions-can-you-play-as-the-zerg), which says there are no Zerg missions.

Is there any other way to play as the Zerg? Any way at all? As I said, I'm new. The only ways I can find to play are campaigns and multiplayer. I don't want to play multiplayer; I'm a casual player who just wants to entertain myself at my own pace.

Comment: It's an extremely broad question.  You could simply play as them.  That's the best way to learn

Comment: The downvotes are people telling you that this question is broad or vague. This isn't a question that can be answered well. Even the current answer to your question won't help you much. Is there any other way to play as Zerg? Yeah there are tons. The campaign will help a lot, playing against bots will help a lot, reading forums and watching tutorial videos will help...there isn't just one way to get you to play a certain race. I personally suggest the campaign as it's fantastic in every way and then go into the Arcade and play fun unique scenarios.

Comment: The question you linked states that there are no missions in StarCraft II: **Wings of Liberty** to play as zerg. Aside from WoL, Starcraft 2 constists of two entire expansions and a mission pack - there must be a zerg campaign somewhere in there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Heart of the Swarm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarCraft_II:_Heart_of_the_Swarm) expansion provides a Campaign with Zerg missions.

Additionally, you can play as Zerg in a match with just AI, which can be set to a low difficulty to allow you to learn.